# Align text like in math mode

Tags: math-mode, positioning

My question is pretty basic but I couldn't find any solutions to this. 
I'm looking for something to align text; in math mode you can use the & to mark where the next line of code should be aligned. Does something like that exist in text mode, too?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `tabular`  uses `&` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

David Carlisle suggests `tabular`, which is good.  But there is also the `tabbing` environment.  In the first line of `tabbing` you set one or more alignment points with `\=`; in subsequent lines you align with `\>`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
  Here is some text.  \=Alignment point set.\\
  \>Under alignment point.\\
  Text.\>Text.
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```